# how to display and hide text on mouse over using jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function Hover() {
    //display something inside div id=dynamicDivFirstModule
} 
function HoverClear() {
    //clear//
}
```

```html
<div ID="dynamicDivFirstModule"  >
<%--  Dynamic Div--%>
    <div id="dynamicDiv"  style="display:none; border:solid;" >
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1" rowspan="2">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" style="overflow:auto;" Height="102px" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
                 </td>
                <td id="hoverHere">
                     <p id="hover" class="masterTooltip" onmouseover="Hover();" onmouseOut="HoverClear()">?</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="removeDiv" />        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>   
  <%--  Dynamic Div--%>
</div>
```

on mouseover I want to display a text..  how can i display a text inside id=dynamicDivFirstModule ..text will display on mouse pointer tip and disappear on mouseout

Comment: what element should have the hover effect? i mean, which element to hover for displaying the div content?

Comment: @Syed  does any answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<div id="dynamicDivFirstModule" style="height:600; width:500; background-color:red;">something else</br>
<span id="textSpan" style="display:none;">Text appears</span>
</div>




$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dynamicDivFirstModule").on('mouseenter',function() {
        $("#textSpan").show();
    });
    $("#dynamicDivFirstModule").on('mouseout',function() {
        $("#textSpan").hide();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tariquasar/zatau6r4/)

In your case change the code likewise,
make the hover paragraph display none initially

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hoverHere").on('mouseenter',function() {
        $("#hover").show();
    });
    $("#hoverHere").on('mouseout',function() {
        $("#hover").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said that you want text to appear over mouse pointer tip I developed this code, It might help you.

html

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<span id="textSpan" style="display:none;position:absolute;"></span>
```

css

```
div{
  width: 10px;
  cursor :default;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").on('mouseover',function(e) {
    var div = $(this).html();
    $("#textSpan").html(div).css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY-15}).show();
});
    $("div").on('mouseout',function(e) {
     $("#textSpan").hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cup6o3hn/3/

Answer (score 0):

A simple jQuery hover function would do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hoverHere").hover(
       function() 
       {
          $("#hover").show();
       },
       function() 
       {
          $("#hover").hide();
       }
    );
});
```